# How to save new added elements on a HTML file to its own file on local disk?

Tags: javascript, jquery

NOTE: This is just an HTML file on local disk. No server at all. Instead of using a HTML editor to modify HTML content of that file, I would like to use it's own GUI on browser to modify.

I have a HTML file with a table and a button named "Add new row". When I click the button, a new row is added to the table.

How can I keep that new row inside the HTML file structure, so when I refresh the HTML page, the row I have added lately will be still there?

I hope you understand my thinking :)

Comment: Store the change in a data store on the server side, and read it back out when the page is next loaded. Writing HTML to a server-side file that's publicly accessible is a really bad idea.

Comment: Is every user of the site supposed to have their own table, or is there just one table that everybody shares?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What you're attempting to do (dynamically modify an HTML document and use the local hard disk to save state) used to be relatively straight forward, but due to severe security concerns now requires that you also create a browser plugin (or other utility, such as a locally hosted web server) that can execute 'write' commands to save the HTML DOM state to disk.

I recommend you look closely at the code for https://tiddlywiki.com/. It may *be* the solution you're looking for; or at least it will illustrate the complexity of writing HTML DOM state to disk.

Comment: This seems a solution for me. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could be helpful. It would also help me if you could 'vote up' this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

1. Send the data to server using Ajax and update the file one server. You need backend script for this.
2. Store new data in LocalStorage and update on init. It will be accessible only from same browser that added new html.

And if you want to modify local file (same machine as the browser) there is new API that probably will allow this, if user give permission to write file on disc, but this will be the same as localStorage, only for single person. I think what you really want is Ajax.

Comment: This answer fails to accommodate the key requirement in the question: how to save "on local disk".

Comment: @dns you can't save to local disk, the option is only to save on the server. There is some new API spec for local files save but I think they are not implemented yet. There is some other API to access local files but I think it's only for reading.